# multiply in where with eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi i am trying to run this sql query in laravel using eloquent

```
SELECT name FROM `products` WHERE `price` * `quantity` >= 100;
```

In sql I get the expected result

in laravel with eloquent I am trying with this:

```
$products = product::where(DB::raw('(price * quantity >= 100)'))->pluck('name');
```

Result

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1277 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

How can I execute this query well?

Comment: with this it worked: $products = product::whereRaw('price * quantity >= 100')->pluck('name');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereRaw`

```
$products = product::whereRaw('price * quantity >= 100')->pluck('name');
```

or

```
 $products = product::where(DB::raw('price * quantity'),'>=','100')->pluck('name');
```